# calculation with jquery does not work properly

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I will do my best in English but there may be errors.

I'm working on a script that retrieves miles from Google Maps. The retrieves miles has to be multiplied whit a number I choose. Retrieving the miles is not a problem...its the multiplied.

It has to do it automatically, but it only multiplied when I change some numbers from the retrieves miles.

Its like is only working when I put some numbers in the input and not when Google Maps put it.

I hope you may understand what I mean in this video [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksAIVJHuW4k).

**HTML**

```
<input class="calculate" type="text" name="start" id="start" placeholder="VERTREK ADRES" />
<input class="calculate" type="text" name="end" id="end" placeholder="AANKOMST ADRES" />
<input id="first" class="calculate aantal " type="number" name="distance" placeholder="AANTAL KM" />
<select id=second class="calculate span5">
    <option value=2>value 2</option>
    <option value=1.50>LANCIA</option>
</select>
<br />
<p style="color:#FFF; font-size:20px;">Prijs totaal:<span id=added></span></p>
<br />
<BUTTON class="CALCULATEB span3" type="submit" value="ROUTE NAKIJKEN" onclick="calcRoute()">ROUTE NAKIJKEN</BUTTON>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">         
$('input').keyup(function () {     
  // run anytime the value changes
  var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val()); // get value of field
  var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val()); // convert it to a float
  var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#third').val());
  $('#added').html(firstValue * secondValue); // add them and output it
});     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you only have it running on the keyup code...

put it in a function like so....

```
    function getMiles(){
    var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val()); // get value of field
    var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val()); // convert it to a float
    var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#third').val());
    $('#added').html(firstValue * secondValue ); 

    }
```

Then you can run that code, on keyup for anytime it changes....and just run it any other time you need to....like when page loads etc...

```
$('input').keyup(getMiles); //this will do as you had it before...


 getMiles();//this can be used at top of script, or in a callback, 
            //so that it updates on page load, or on the google map callback
```

Like for example, I don't know how you are getting the data from google, but lets pretend its a Jquery Ajax call....then you would just call `getMiles()` in the success function....like this...

```
$.ajax({
   url: "googlemapexample.php",
   dataType: "json",
   success: getMiles
   });
```

Or in the done function....so you can do other stuff on scuccess....

```
    $.ajax({
   url: "googlemapexample.php",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data){
    ///do some stuff here with data
    } }).done(getMiles);
```